# Find the domain and range of $h(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Given $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\arctan(nx);g(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sin^{2n}x$ and $\sin(h(x))=\frac{1}{2}[\cos\pi\times g(x)+\cos(2f(x))]$.Find the domain and range of $h(x)$.

In this question,i was not able to find the $f(x)$ in terms of $x$,$g(x)=0$,i know.How should i find the domain and range of $h(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $f(x)=-\pi/2 , x\in(-\infty,0)$, $f(0)=0$, $f(x)=\pi/2, x\in(0,\infty)$.

$g(x)=0,x\neq \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}, k\in\mathbb Z\,$ and $\,g(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2})=1, k\in\mathbb Z$ Now consider these cases to plug in $$\sin(h(x))=\frac{1}{2}[-1\cdot g(x)+\cos (2f(x))]$$

You get 
$$\sin(h(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}))=\frac{1}{2}[-1-1]=-1, x=\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}, k\in\mathbb Z$$
$$\sin(h(0))=\frac{1}{2}[0+1]=\frac{1}{2},x=0$$
$$\sin(h(x))=\frac{1}{2}[0-1]=-\frac{1}{2},x\in (-\infty,\infty)\setminus (\{\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}, k\in\mathbb Z\}\cup \{0\})$$
I leave for you to determine what is $h(x)$ and what should be the domain in order $h(x)$ to be really a function. i,e to for each $x$ to have exactly one image $h(x)$.

Comment: In the answer,the domain of $h(x)$ is $R$,that i got,but the range of $h(x)$ is $\frac{n\pi}{2},n\in I$,I is set of integers.But $\sin(h(x))$ is not $-1$ according to your post.Is the answer given in the book not correct?@Svetoslav.

Comment: Is it $\cos( \pi g(x))$ or $g(x)\cdot \cos \pi$

Comment: Yes sir,i am very sorry.It was a typo on my part.I just correct it.

Comment: So I have to edit the answer according to this function $g(x)$

Comment: Because $g(x)=0, x\neq \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}$ and $0$ otherwise.